# ListView column auto sizing

Tags: wpf, listview, autosize

Let's say I have the following ListView:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Something" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShortText}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Description"
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VeryLongTextWithCRs}" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Something Else" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AnotherShortText}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I'd like the short text columns to always fit in the screen, and the long text column to use the remaining space, word-wrapping if necessary.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this with a GridListView since it doesn't support setting the width of a column to "*" (fill remaining space).

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/83bd7ab9-3407-461f-a0bc-69e04870075c) is a discussion of how you could fake it by using an IValueConverter to set the width of the column to TotalListWidth - SumOfColumnWidths

On the other hand, have you considered using a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead? This will support the kind of layout you are looking for, though is a considerably heavier control. It is also only native in .NET 4 - though you can get an equivalent for 3.5 through the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535).

Comment: Martin, the problem with the IValueConverter solution is that it requires all the other widths to be set (I'd rather not set any). At this point, I can't change the ListViews in this project, but I'll definitely using DataGrid for the next one. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid the datagrid if you can! It's a pile of crap and full of bugs

Answer (score 7):

```
<Grid Name="dummygrid" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Name="dummywidth1"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Name="dummywidth2"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" Name="dummywidth3"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="3" Name="dummywidth4"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="5" Name="dummywidth5"></Border>
        </Grid>
        <ListView  Name="Installer_LV" Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LV_ItemStyle}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  AlternationCount="2">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource LV_HeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding ElementName=dummywidth1, Path=ActualWidth}"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="DisplayName" Click="InstallerLV_HeaderClick">Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding ElementName=dummywidth2, Path=ActualWidth}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Publisher}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Publisher" Click="InstallerLV_HeaderClick">Publisher</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding ElementName=dummywidth3, Path=ActualWidth}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Version}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Version" Click="InstallerLV_HeaderClick">Version</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding ElementName=dummywidth4, Path=ActualWidth}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Size" Click="InstallerLV_HeaderClick">Size</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button  Height="38" Width="130" Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButton}" Content="{Binding Status}" Tag="{Binding ModuleId}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="onActionClick"></Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

In the above example i have used a dummy grid and split into 5 columns and using binding assign that size to "GridViewColum" by

> Width="{Binding ElementName=dummywidth4, Path=ActualWidth}"

So that when the hidden dummy grid column size changes it will get reflect in gridview column size also.

Comment: This is insane ... I LOVE IT

Answer (score 6):

Set `Width="Auto"` on your GridViewColumns.  However, due to virtualization you may encounter some problems with auto-sizing.

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560581/how-to-autosize-and-right-align-gridviewcolumn-data-in-wpf)

So, long-story-short, if you want accurate auto-sizing of columns you'll need to recalculate your widths when the visible data changes, due to virtualization.

Comment: Isn't Auto the default? The problem is, it seems to create horizontal scrolling because it expands beyond the available space.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, toggling the `Width` to `ActualWidth` and then back to `NaN` for any columns that don't have widths explicitly set.  This will only work if the listview columns do not contain controls.  I usually call this after data in the list has changed.

```
Public Shared Sub AutoResizeListView(lst As Windows.Controls.ListView)
    Dim gv = DirectCast(lst.View, Windows.Controls.GridView)
    For Each gvc In gv.Columns
        If Double.IsNaN(gvc.Width) Then
            gvc.Width = gvc.ActualWidth
            gvc.Width = Double.NaN
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First set the name in the column header like so:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="350" x:Name="lvhDescription"/>
```

And then on resize modify width.

```
Private Sub winMain_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged


    If Me.IsLoaded = False Then Exit Sub

    lvhDescription.Width = e.NewSize.Width - 665


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to present an another approach in order to size each column with the largest element width.
Do this following on each list view item with the help of a loop.

No need to change size after a re-size window event.

Leaves **UnitWidth** as the constant font width size.

You can also define a delegate to the SourceUpdated event.

```
GridView gv = (myListView.View as GridView);
if (titleLen < c.Title.Length)
{
    titleLen = c.Title.Length;
    gv.Columns[0].Width = titleLen * UnitWidth;
}
if (cssLen < c.CSSName.Length)
{
    cssLen = c.CSSName.Length;
    gv.Columns[1].Width = cssLen * UnitWidth;
}
if (valueLen < c.Value.Length)
{
    valueLen = c.Value.Length;
    gv.Columns[2].Width = valueLen * UnitWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead,

```
  private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double remainingSpace = mylistviewname.ActualWidth;

        if (remainingSpace > 0)
        {

            (mylistviewname.View as GridView).Columns[1].Width = Math.Ceiling(remainingSpace / 3);
            (mylistviewname.View as GridView).Columns[2].Width = Math.Ceiling(remainingSpace / 3);
            (mylistviewname.View as GridView).Columns[3].Width = Math.Ceiling(remainingSpace / 3);
        }
    }
```

Here i user SizeChanged event so when the windows size change this function is triggered and update the width of the listviewheader. I have 3 listviewheaders so divided by 3 if you have more than 3 divide by appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="someList">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width={Binding ElementName=someList, Path=ActualWidth/3} Header="Something" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShortText}" />
      <GridViewColumn  Width={Binding ElementName=someList, Path=ActualWidth/3} Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=VeryLongTextWithCRs}" />
      <GridViewColumn  Width={Binding ElementName=someList, Path=ActualWidth/3} Header="Something Else" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AnotherShortText}" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```