# How to Resize Dynamically width of a WPF DataGrid Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, width, datagridcolumn

I Have a DataGrid in my Window, and i need to automatically resize the column's width to fit content. But i have an obstacle:

- If his content is smaller than his header, the size of the header should prevail;
- His content is automatically update by a Binding, linked to a TextBox. So... when user focuses to another field, the column representing that field will update. It already happens when the newest content is bigger than the previous data.
- I'm using MVVM, and this component its a UserControl extended of a DataGrid. I can't use some resources than we have in Code-Behind, but i could use (it's not a best way to do) MVVM Binding to resize it. I really want do make a generic solution.

I'll appreciate for any help.

Best regards,

Gustavo.

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549099/datagrid-column-width-doesnt-auto-update, columns won't shrink automatically.
If I understand you correctly, that's your problem?

Comment: Yes, and we really need to shrink automatically. I'll gonna read this article and try to implement it.
Thanks.