# WPF Datagrid Column Width Issue

Tags: wpf, datagrid, width

I have columns in a `DataGrid` that are being set by an `ObservableCollection` that is the type of a simple data object that I created. The first column has a width set to "**Auto**" and the second column as a width set to "**1***".

I am currently using the method in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549099/datagrid-column-width-doesnt-auto-update) to autoupdate the width of my column that is set to "Auto" when the `ItemsSource` changes. This seems to work most of the time:

[image]
**This looks great, and works all of the time**

Although, when the `ItemsSource` is a little bit larger (lets say about 30-35 records), the "Auto" width (first) column will shrink down ***only*** when the `DataGrid` (including the scroll bar) is *clicked*:

[image] **This will be resized properly if it hasn't been clicked**

My XAML looks like this:

```
 <my:DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="false" CanUserResizeRows="false" CanUserResizeColumns="false" CanUserReorderColumns="false" CanUserDeleteRows="false" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns ="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" Height="113" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,22,0,0" Name="dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" Background="#FFE2E2E2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFA4CFF2" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="dataGrid_BeginningEdit" PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit" SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" Loaded="dataGrid_Loaded" TargetUpdated="dataGrid_TargetUpdated">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Width="Auto">
                <my:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                 </my:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
              </my:DataGridTextColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="1*"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
   </my:DataGrid.Columns>
 </my:DataGrid>
```

The code to assure the updating of the column:

```
 private void dataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.Columns[0].Width = 0;
        dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        dataGrid.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
        dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Is there any reason this may be happening only when the list is longer like this?

Answer (score 1):

DataGrid's `TargetUpdated` might not get called in a few scenarios. For example, when you have more rows coming in but they are not visible then the datagrid doesn't have to "waste cycles on" re-rendering something that is not visible. The initial `TargetUpdated` is fine, but you might have to find an additional hook, and do similar thing there, such as hooking into the `CollectionChanged` of the object that's bound to `ItemsSource` of your `datagrid`, your  `observableCollection` has the event `CollectionChanged`, subscribe and try your logic there.