# Resizing grids' size and filling the whole columns and rows with grids while enlarging the Main Window in WPFA

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a grid that consists several columns and rows. Inside of some columns and rows there are datagrids. Here is the question: How can i dynamically resize all grids in different columns and rows while I am enlarging the main window? I created all columns and rows like Height="x*" and Width="y*". In other words rows and columns are being resized while the main window is being resized but grids' size remains the same. I want to enlarge all grids and fill the whole column with the grid. I tried to fix grids' size with * and it did not work. Any idea how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It would be helpful for folks who want to help see a concept of what you want with some of your code added and/or visuals of some sort to better convey your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The default layout behaviour of WPF should give you what you expect.

For example, if you have only this in a Window:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```

The DataGrid should size with the window as you resize it, occupying exactly a quarter of the window in the top left corner.

**Be careful that you aren't setting VerticalAlignment or HorizontalAlignment to something other than "Stretch".**

If you mean to ask how to size the columns of the **DataGrid** dynamically, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549099/datagrid-column-width-doesnt-auto-update).

Comment: As a side note, `<RowDefinition/>` is the same as `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` by default if you want to omit the extra xaml.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved while enlarging window :) But while shrinking it did not help. I had 2 data grids  and 1 grid one under another in {row0,column2}. Although i set all elements' alignments to "strech" it didnt work out . As a final solution I defined MinHeight and MinWidth for MainWindow .

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.