# Dynamically resize datagrid columns when rows are collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid control, dgChangesMade, with ItemsSource = `ObservableCollection<CheckinPath>`.

The first column, dgPath, is a DataGridTemplateColumn, consisting of

- CheckBox
- TextBlock. A converter returns for the latter a relative path.
  The visibility of a datagrid row is bound to the IsVisible property.

Besides the DataGrid control, I also have a CheckBox control:

- IsChecked event is bound to the boolean property IsChecked. The setter sets the IsVisible property of objects bound to the item source of the DataGrid. Therefore datagrid rows are collapsed/shown when the checkbox is (un)checked.
- SourceUpdated event is bound to CheckBox_SourceUpdated

Like Scott pointed out in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651287/7779143):

> The DataGrid will increase column sizes to fit as the data becomes
>   longer, but it does not automatically decrease column sizes when the
>   length of the data decreases

So in the CheckBox_SourceUpdated event I

1. set column widths to 0
2. force an update layout of the DataGrid
3. set column widths to Auto

Unfortunately that didn't help.
When (un)checking the checkbox control, the column widths increases when needed (see 2 in screenshot) but aren't automatically decreased according to the length of the data in the datagrid columns (see 3 in screenshot, 3 shows the same content as 1).

Any ideas?

**Screenshot**
[image]

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name='dgChangesMade' Width='Auto' ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChangesMade}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width='Auto' x:Key='dgPath' Header='Path' IsReadOnly='True' x:Shared='False'>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal' VerticalAlignment='Center'>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked='{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}'>
                    <TextBlock Text='{Binding Converter={StaticResource CheckinPathConverter}, ConverterParameter="Path"}' />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <Style x:Key='dgShowHideRow' TargetType='DataGridRow'>
            <Setter Property='Visibility' Value='{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter="Collapsed", Mode=TwoWay}' />
        </Style>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey='dgPath' />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey='dgStatus' />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey='dgLock' />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey='dgShowHideRow' />
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
<!-- Setter of this checkbox sets the IsVisible property of the datagrid bound objects -->
<CheckBox IsChecked='{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}' SourceUpdated='CheckBox_SourceUpdated'/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void CheckBox_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var c in dgChangesMade.Columns)
        c.Width = 0;

    dgChangesMade.UpdateLayout();
    foreach (var c in dgChangesMade.Columns)
        c.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class CheckinPath : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_isVisible != value)
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: You could try forcing the whole datagrid to re-read the data. Set ChangesMade to null and then back to the filtered collection. Might work.  Might not, I'd have to give it a go myself and see what happened. Assuming the property raises propertychanged.

Comment: Or call .refresh() on the collectionview of ChangesMade.

Comment: @Andy I don't think clearing all data in a datagrid is good practice for filtering the datagrid. In the meantime I solved the issue myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

1. Instead of binding the datagrid itemsource to an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), it is now bound to [CollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx). 
   In this way rows in the datagrid can be shown/hidden by using the [CollectionViewSource Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property.
   The filtering takes place in the ViewModel.
2. After the [CollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) has been filtered,  The column widths of the datagrid is resetted.
   Because a datagrid is a control, the reset takes place in the code behind of the view (using Messenger from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight))

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name='dg'
            ItemsSource='{Binding ChangesMadeView}'
            AutoGenerateColumns='False'
            IsReadOnly='True' .../>
<CheckBox IsChecked='{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}' .../>
```

**Window code behind**

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly Guid Token = new Guid();
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, Token, ResetColumnWidth);
    }

    private void ResetColumnWidth(NotificationMessage notMessage)
    {
        if (notMessage.Notification == "ResetColumnWidth")
        {
            foreach (DataGridColumn c in dg.Columns)
            {
                c.Width = 0;
                c.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private IList<CheckinPath> _changesMade = new List<CheckinPath>();
public ICollectionView ChangesMadeView { get; private set; }

public TestViewModel()
{
    LoadData(); //Loads data for _changesMade
    ChangesMadeView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_changesMade);
}

private bool _isChecked;

public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        if (_isChecked != value)
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
            ChangesMadeView.Filter = checkinPath => { //do logic for filtering. Returns true or false ;};
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("ResetColumnWidth"), TestWindow.Token); //notify the code behind of the view
        };
    }
}
```