# How can a ListBox fill its parent width?

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` and need that it fills the parent's width but have not found a way to do it, the `ListBox` has always the `ListBox` width and not the 100%.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding anagSearchResults}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Gray"
     SelectedItem="{Binding selectCustomer}" 
     FontSize="14"    
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
           </Style>
     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                    ....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate question. I think the answer you are looking for at [How to get a ListBox ItemTemplate to stretch horizontally the full width of the ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the).

Answer (score 2):

I would check the HorizontalAlignment of the parent(s) and make sure none of them are set to left, right or centre.

Comment: Also it might be because one of the parents' width property has been set to a fixed value.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with a ListView GridView.
Then for width you need to use a converter.
Change the converter in this sample to be parent width / 4

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083933/gridviewcolumn-width-adjustment/9088071#9088071)

See the checked answer from me