# How do I get Cells in an dataGrid to resize automatically to fit the viewable data?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I have data being loaded into dataGrids.  When it appears.. the Cells aren't autosizing to fit the data.   If one of the excel Cells has  "Hi and welcome to my home"   It would only show "Hi and welcome to ......

I'm looking for the proper grid.xxxx instruction.  I'm doing this in C# and on a windows Form.

```
var tabPage = new TabPage(name1);
                DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();  //{ //Dock = DockStyle.Fill  // };
                grid.Location = new Point(10, 50);
                grid.Size = new Size(950, 450);
                grid.Name = "dg_" + name;

                tabPage.Controls.Add(grid);
                comboBox1.Items.Add(name1);
                tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
                loadData(name, grid);
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/560581/1997232).

Comment: There's also the datagridview's AutoSizeColumnsMode or AutoSizeRowsMode properties.

Comment: An excel file is being imported.  The code looks at the sheets in the excel file, (if 5 sheets), the Form application will create a tab and a dataGridView on each tab on the fly.  So I need the line of code that will tell the cells to go as large as they need to in order to display all the information.   I'm assuming there is a grid.xxxx.xxx

Comment: grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;